# Job to check job state

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to check what it's the state of the previously started jobs without blocking the session I am in.
So I tried something like this:

```
Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
    while($true){
        $i++
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
    }
}

Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
    switch ((Get-Job)[0].State){
        "Stopped" {
            write-host "Stopped"
        }
        "Running"{
            write-host "Running"
        }
        default {
            write-host "Something else"
        }
    }
}

Get-Job | Receive-Job
```

But it throws an error saying that I can not index into a `null` array, even when I have several jobs running.

Is there a way for starting a job that allow me to check the other jobs state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since jobs "live" in different "spaces" (poor technicality, sorry for that), they can't see each other. So, the solution that I found is to run a `ScriptBlock` whenever a `timer` throws an `event`. This way, the other jobs continue undisturbed.

```
Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
    while($true){
        $i++
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
    }
}

$timer = New-Object System.Timers.Timer
$timer.AutoReset = $true #repeat?
$timer.Interval = 500 #ms

Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $timer -EventName Elapsed -Action {   
    $job_state = (Get-Job)[0].State
    switch ($job_state){
        "Stopped" {
            write-host "Stopped"
        }
        "Running"{
            write-host "Running"
        }
        default {
            write-host "Something else"
        }
    }
}

$timer.Start()
```

This way if the first job is in a state that isn't supposed to be, i can be notified.